# run a function in react.js server one time in a day every day

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

```
import express from "express"
import cors from "cors"
import bodyParser from "body-parser"
import { MongoClient, ObjectId} from "MongoDB"

const PORT = process.env.PORT|| 3001;
const app=express()
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log("run");
})
//function that doesn't work
const setUnsetPercentbuysell=()=>{
  if(new Date().getHours()===23 && new Date().getMinutes()===59){
 MongoClient.connect("mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0.pdunp.mongodb.net/<database>?retryWrites=true&w=majority", function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db("player");
      dbo.collection("calcio").updateMany({},{$set:{percentbuysell:{buy:0,sell:0}}},(err,result)=>{
        if (err) throw err;
      })
    })
  }
  setTimeout(setUnsetPercentbuysell,60000)
}
setUnsetPercentbuysell()
```

setUnsetPercentbuysell would be function to run every minutes and do somthing only at 23:59.
So i save this code in my heroku app but doesn't work (MongoClient is not the problem, i wrote ,  and  for my privacy).
can someone help me?

i tried do that code but doesn't work

Comment: Did you mean node.js server?

Comment: yes i mean node.js server

Comment: Heroku will put your app to slip every 20 minutes. You should use cron or some kind of scheduler https://github.com/gliffy/canvas2svg/blob/master/canvas2svg.js

Comment: so can i put this code in my heroku app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cron` package for node to achieve that.

The usage will look like this:

```js
import {CronJob} from 'cron';

const run = () => {
  MongoClient.connect("mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0.pdunp.mongodb.net/<database>?retryWrites=true&w=majority", function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;

    dbo.collection("calcio").updateMany({},{$set:{percentbuysell:{buy:0,sell:0}}},(err,result)=>{
      if (err) throw err;
    })
  })
}

const job = new CronJob('59 59 23 * * *', run);

job.start()
```

This will run the job every day at 23:59 and 59 seconds.

Make sure to check out [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) to learn more on how it works.

Comment: so can i put this code in my heroku app?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work with heroku. Look at [heroku scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler)

Comment: This should work with heroku as it doesn't run your application serverless.